# I need to fetch records grouped datewise(dates) ,daywise(monday,tuesday,....sunday) and hourwise(1,2,3...23,24) in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, express, mongodb-query

Below is the format of mongo table records

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("656efc1366c7dce6da3185e3"),
    a: '656e5e0c6c773c4374b0b14a',
    b: '656e5e346c773c4374b0b14b',
    c: 'abc',
    d: '656dbcda6c773c4374b0b125',
    e: '656e5e346c773c4374b0b14d',
    f: 1,
    date: '2023-12-05 10:31:47'
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId("656efc1466c7dce6da3185e5"),
    a: '656e5e0c6c773c4374b0b14a',
    b: '656e5e346c773c4374b0b14b',
    c: 'def',
    d: '656dbcda6c773c4374b0b125',
    e: '656e5e346c773c4374b0b14d',
    f: 2,
    date: '2023-12-05 10:31:48'
  }
```

I need 3 seperate queries to group the records datewise, daywise and hourwise and display count of records with filter

Output expected

```
1/1/2023  2
2/1/2023  3
--------------------------------
monday   2
tuesday  3
--------------------------------------
between 12:00-1:00       1
between 1:00-2:00        2
between 23:00-24:00      5
```

Tried this for date but dint work

```
db.collection.aggregate([ { $match: { "d": "656dbcda6c773c4374b0b125", "b": "656e5e346c773c4374b0b14b" } }, { $group: { _id: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date" } }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }] );
```

MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $dateToString parameter 'date' must be coercible to date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query currently doesn't work since your `date` field is a String that doesn't match the ISOFormat "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ". So you should first parse it from string to date with a custom format.

According to the [official documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/), you could try something like this :

```
{ $dateFromString: {
 dateString: "$date",
 format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
} }
```

The full query i would do for your issue would look like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  //match whatever you want
  {
    $match: {
      "d": "656dbcda6c773c4374b0b125",
      "b": "656e5e346c773c4374b0b14b"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "formattedDate": {
        "$dateFromString": {
          dateString: "$date",
          format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$facet": {
      "totalCountStage": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": "totalCount",
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
              "$arrayToObject": [
                [
                  {
                    "k": "$_id",
                    "v": "$count"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "countDateWise": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "$dateToString": {
                "date": "$formattedDate",
                "format": "%d/%m/%Y"
              }
            },
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
              "$arrayToObject": [
                [
                  {
                    "k": "$_id",
                    "v": "$count"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "countHourWise": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "$concat": [
                "between ",
                {
                  "$dateToString": {
                    "date": "$formattedDate",
                    "format": "%H"
                  }
                },
                ":00-",
                {
                  $substrCP: [
                    {
                      $add: [
                        {
                          $toLong: {
                            "$dateToString": {
                              "date": "$formattedDate",
                              "format": "%H"
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        101
                      ]
                    },
                    1,
                    2
                  ]
                },
                ":00"
              ]
            },
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
              "$arrayToObject": [
                [
                  {
                    "k": "$_id",
                    "v": "$count"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "countDayWise": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": {
              "$dateToString": {
                "date": "$formattedDate",
                "format": "%u"
              }
            },
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            _id: {
              $switch: {
                branches: [
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "1"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "monday"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "2"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "tuesday"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "3"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "wednesday"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "4"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "thursday"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "5"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "friday"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "6"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "saturday"
                  },
                  {
                    case: {
                      $eq: [
                        "$_id",
                        "7"
                      ]
                    },
                    then: "sunday"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
              "$arrayToObject": [
                [
                  {
                    "k": "$_id",
                    "v": "$count"
                  }
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it for yourself on [mongoplayground.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZlTK9GtkVSm)

Hope that helps !

Comment: This worked..Thankyou

Comment: Great ! The best way to thank me is by accepting the answer since it fixed your problem ! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers